# Community detection reduce increase levels NEO4J

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I am using Neo4J and the gds library. I have a graph dataset, where each node are connected to every node giving them some weight. There are multiple links between each pair of nodes (but different weights). I want to use any Community detection algorythm as Louvain, WCC..., but all of the available give always 1 big Community, or 2. I want to have 20 or 30 differentiated communities as a result.
Do you know any way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

> but all of the available give always 1 big Community, or 2

It's wrong.

This depends on your data and how you run your algorithm. I think you can read and explore more in [Graph Algorithms Manual](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/algorithms/)

Comment: I read and explore all possible algorithm, none of them worked properly. That guides are just useless, since they do not explain in depth